# No known class method for selector 'setRegion:animated:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

I tried some stuff in xcode, and i'm using this code for my MapView.

> No known class method for selector `'setRegion:animated:'`

I have made three View Controller with with 3 .h and .m files.

What's my mistake?

.m

```
#import "myPlacesAllTime.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>



@interface myPlacesAllTime ()

@end

@implementation myPlacesAllTime

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        MKCoordinateRegion startRegion = { {0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0} };
        startRegion.center.latitude = 35.88905;
        startRegion.center .longitude = -17.605591;
        startRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
        startRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1;
        [myPlacesAllTime setRegion:startRegion animated: NO];
    }
```

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface myPlacesAllTime : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>{

    __weak IBOutlet MKMapView *myPlacesAllTime;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have chosen the same name `myPlacesAllTime` for the *class* and for an
*instance variable* of that class.

To solve the problem, rename the class, e.g. to `MyPlacesController` or similar.
 Note that the convention is to let
class names start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem may be a naming issue.  The class you've created is named the same as the instance of MKMapView you have.  I would follow convention and name your class with caps, but to solve the current problem try using

```
[self.myPlacesAllTime setRegion:startRegion animated:NO];
```

to see if it has a different outcome.  You'll have to make your instance a property of the class, as stated in the comments below, which I missed in my original answer.

Comment: It's declared as an instance variable and not a property so `self.` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to use `setRegion:animated:` at class level then make sure you have defined a method like this:

`+ (void)setRegion:(OBJ_Type)iType animated:(OBJ_Type)iAnimated {`

And f you are intending to use `setRegion:animated:` at object level then make sure you have defined a method like this:

`- (void)setRegion:(OBJ_Type)iType animated:(OBJ_Type)iAnimated {`

and in this case you need to call this method like this:

```
[self setRegion:PARAM animated:PARAM];
```